# ECMAScript modules in Workers for Firefox, but it only works sometimes? (Comlink)

Tags: typescript, firefox, es6-modules, web-worker, comlink

I'm a bit confused, and I think I'm just confusing myself more.

Firefox apparently *does not* support [ECMAScript modules inside Workers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_worker_worker_ecmascript_modules), however I'm getting inconsistent performance with it. I have a project that uses Comlink and ES6 modules. When I ran it in Firefox, it seemed to work fine.

... Until yesterday, we had a client on Firefox 100 who's getting `DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.`. I've installed numerous versions of Firefox on numerous devices, and I can't seem to recreate the issue. I had the client reset their browser, but no luck fixing it.

My Comlink worker is something like this:

```js
import { FetchFromId } from "./deobf";

export const Fetch = async (id: string): Promise<CustomObject | Error> => {
    return FetchFromId(id);
};
```

And it's called like this:

```js
import { FetchFromId } from "./deobf";

if (window.Worker) {
  WORKER = new ComlinkWorker<typeof import('./worker')>(new URL('./worker', import.meta.url), { type: "module" });
}
const res = await (WORKER ? WORKER.Fetch(id) : FetchFromId(id)); // DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned
```

(`ComlinkWorker` is from [here](https://github.com/mathe42/vite-plugin-comlink))

When I run this in Firefox 100, should it not throw an error because it's not supported?

Comment: https://github.com/mathe42/vite-plugin-comlink#module-worker

Comment: That's right, and if you look at the caniuse table, you'll see that Firefox does not support it. My question is "why is it working for me", and further, "why is it only working for some people".

Comment: Aren't you using the bundled version? The code you provided seems to be running from the main context, there FF does support module scripts. As for why it doesn't work for some users, not sure. That error sounds like someone tried to postMessage an Error object or at least some object that can't be cloned in FF. Might not be related to module scripts at all.

Comment: You're right, it didn't hit me for some reason. You're probably right then. Maybe I'll open an issue there, or investigate further. Thanks